# Where do I get oracle performance tuner for glassfish 3.1 admin console

Tags: performance, glassfish, admin

Does anyone know how to get the Oracle performance tuner (referred to in this link: http://www.java.net/external?url=http://blogs.oracle.com/jenblog/entry/performance_tuner_in_oracle_glassfish) installed in the admin console?

Installed in the Glassfish 3.1 admin console?  I can't find an Add-on with that name, it isn't installed by default and it doesn't show up for me on the left hand side of the admin console under resources like it shows in the performance tuning video tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure you download the Oracle version.

http://glassfish.java.net/

Comment: Thanks!  Turns out it's not available in the Open Source community addition.