# Log Rotation Manager in Glassfish 3.1.1 Open Source Edition

Tags: logging, configuration, glassfish-3

I would like to remove old log files created by Glassfish 3.1.1.

It used to be possible through the Log Rotation Manager: https://blogs.oracle.com/sirajg/entry/managing_rotated_log_files

However, it is not available in the free edition: [Where do I get oracle performance tuner for glassfish 3.1 admin console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236276/where-do-i-get-oracle-performance-tuner-for-glassfish-3-1-admin-console)

Is there any other way to change those settings?

Answer (score 1):

There are some logging options in Configurations > server-config > Logger Settings.
Obviously limited but it should address most of the demands.